# Django - Aggregate sum of difference between datetime column

Tags: sql, django, orm, aggregate-functions

I have UserSession models that record first_action and last_action datetime columns,
I want to know how long a user spent in the app - that is the sum of the difference between the two (ignoring those with Null last_action).

Unfortunately django ORM aggregate functions only work on a single column, so for the sake of efficiency (there can be thousands of sessions per user) I wrote it in raw SQL, but because I got some high numbers I compared to a python sum.  I don't know why, but the two calculations do not show the same result, can you help me figure it out?

Python:

```
sum(((us.last_action - us.first_action) for us in UserSession.objects.filter(user_id=1234) if us.last_action), datetime.timedelta(0))
```

SQL:

```
select sum(last_action - first_action) as total_time   from usersession where user_id = 1234 and last_action is not null;
```

Comment: The easiest way to diagnose the problem would be to check the actual sql query that is constructed from Python. If you don't know how to do that yourself you can use Django debug toolbar (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar/0.8.5) to list all the sql'l that are produced during page generation. Post back the sqls' so we can help you out.

Comment: the django code is minimalistic - just filter all usersessions for a certain user, the difference and summing and filtering is done in python.  Seems the error is in the raw sql query I wrote, not the python code.

Comment: I get it, but without ability to see the database or query generated by python how would you expect us to tell what can be wrong? Not enough information for my taste...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem - I don't know what subtracting one datetime from another does in mysql, but it wasn't what I wanted.

The correct SQL query is:

```
select sum(timestampdiff(SECOND, first_action, last_action )) as total_time  from usersession where user_id = 123 and last_action is not null
```

now the sql result is the same as the python result - without pulling all the sessions to memory.